# Laravel 5 relation between 3 tables

Tags: laravel-5

I have these 3 tables: `users`, `recipes`and `votes`

user votes on a recipe

> a recipe has many votes
>
> a user has many votes
>
> a user can only vote once on a recipe

In my view i run into a problem, when I try to access the vote rating of a user on the recipe like:(`$recipe->user->vote->rating`), it returns the first vote rating of that user (might be the vote of that user on another recipe)

my relations are:
**User.php**:

```
public function vote()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Vote');
}
```

**Recipe.php**:

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}
```

**Vote.php**:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}

public function recipe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe','recipe_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would make `$user->votes` a hasMany relationship, since there are multiple votes per user.  Then you can create two custom query scopes on the `vote` model:

**User.php**:

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}
```

**Vote.php**:

```
public function scopeByUser($query, $user_id){
    return $query->where('user_id',$user_id);
}

public function scopeOnRecipe($query, $recipe_id){
    return $query->where('recipe_id',$recipe_id);
}
```

These can be used like:

```
$recipe->votes()->byUser($id)->first();

$user->votes()->onRecipe($id)->first();
```

Comment: that seems to work just fine, didn't think of scopes. Thanks